# Django south, remove a specific migration

Tags: django, django-south

In the process of learning south I've made some mistakes which I'd like to recitfy.  Here's one of them:

```
# migrate --list
(*) 0002_auto__add_lesson #add the table
(*) 0003_auto__del_lesson #dammit, table uses wrong db engine so delete it
(*) 0004_auto__add_lesson #recreate the table
```

Clearly, I can just run step 4 and 2 and 3 won't be applied if they're starred:

```
./migrate my_app 0004
```

But as step 2 and 3 are redundant and don't need to be run, is it possible to simply remove them?  Also, I should add Im worried someone might just run migrate which would then delete the table (and any data) and then recreate it...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you run `... migrate my_app 0004` you will apply migrations 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two considerations here.

First, if you have already run a migration, then it's recorded in database and if you just remove a file than you will run into problems: your database will refer to non-existent migration. There is a solution: run migrations 2 and 3 backwards with `./manage.py migrate my_app 0001`, then delete migration files. If you can't migrate back (e.g. you messed up with your database manually) then you can fake migrate back with `./manage.py migrate my_app 0001 --fake` and set up database as it should be manually. Fake means that no schema altering would be done, but notes of migrations run will be removed.

Second, you pushed you code and someone else have run your migrations. In this case you need to create a new migration that reverts anything you've done with 2 and 3. This way anyone will revert unneeded changes by running your new migration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you be a bit more verbose about this bit please? 'run migrations 2 and 3 backwards with ./manage.py migrate my_app 0001, then delete migrations' - I'm not sure exactly what you mean..

Comment: A command `./manage.py migrate my_app <some-number>`. Doesn't run migration `some-number` it runs migrations to the point that everything up to `some-number` is applied. Example 1: you've applied migrations up to 2 inclusively and run `.... 0004` => migrations 3 and 4 are run. Example 2: same position and run `... 0001` => migration 2 is run backwards.

Comment: Sure, just delete them.. that's the whole point of migrations, to be able to go back to migration 1 at any time!

    ./manage.py migrate 0002
    rm <path>migrations/0003....
    rm <path>migrations/0004....

Done.

Comment: Ok, see what you're both saying.  Thanks a lot.  So what I did finally was revert back to 1, deleted 2 and 3, then renamed 4 to to 2 and applied it.  All seems fine but is it ok to rename migrations?

Comment: @rix, ok if it's not applied by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but not recommended.

Step 01:

Unapply all migrations:

`python3 manage.py migrate users zero --fake`

Step 02:
Remove specific migration records from table django_migrations.

Step 03:

Remove the actual migration file from the app/migrations directory.

Step 04:
Open the next migration and refer the dependencies to the previous migration. It's more like a linked list and you want to remove a node from the middle.

Previous > Current (migration to be deleted) > Next

Done!